# Is there a way to set the stage quality in an AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm trying to change the stage quality in a Flex AIR 15 app and it doesn't appear to be working. It doesn't throw any errors but it only returns the value, "HIGH".

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

                       width="600" height="625" 
                       preinitialize="preinitializeHandler(event)"
                       >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.SystemManager;

            protected function preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                systemManager.topLevelSystemManager.stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH_16X16_LINEAR;
                trace("quality=" + systemManager.topLevelSystemManager.stage.quality); // HIGH
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with SystemManager but in a regular AIR app this works:

stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;

Perhaps you are not targeting the stage correctly?

Comment: What device?  Desktop doesn't have HIGH_16X16_LINEAR.

Comment: @moot how do you know this information?

Comment: as3 reference - In the desktop profile of Adobe AIR, quality can be set to StageQuality.BEST or StageQuality.HIGH (and the default value is StageQuality.HIGH). Attempting to set it to another value has no effect (and the property remains unchanged). In the moble profile of AIR, all four quality settings are available.